# How to Deserialize a json encoded array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, deserialization, fetch

I have some problem in the following array, I want to access the value of the "videoid" from the given array that is been fetched with json_encode

```
Array ( [0] => {"DATA":[{"videoid":"462"}]"});
```

Please help me so that I can fetch the value of "videoid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a php string containing JSON and you want to access the videoid property use php's json_decode function :

```
$json='{"DATA":[{"videoid":"462"}]}';
$array=json_decode($json);
var_export(current($array->DATA)->videoid);//returns '462'
```

See the code in action here :

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/485b94b6423972b8c87eec885da8fdc5a56c6acd

Comment: Is there a way i can store it in an variable OR i could store all objects in DATA array in an array ?

Comment: yup, i already figured out to store it in a variable.. thanks a lot BTWay

Answer (score -1):

Here you are. Should work.

If you only want one value I would suggest you make sure to get the json in a different format if possible:

```
$array[0]->data[0]->videoid;
```

If you have more videoids in your DATA than you need to loop it to get it

```
foreach($array[0]->data as $key => $value){
  $dosomethingwithit = $value;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answering, but didn't work for me..  Shows a notice   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in